# Is there any way to protect ourselves from annoying redirects?

Tags: url-redirection

It is not the first time I have been redirected to a malicious site. I was trying to download a song from a website when I clicked on download and was immediately redirected to a page which says "Your phone has been infected with 28% virus, click here to repair". I was surprised how they knew my phone's exact model no. and literally every site redirects to same malicious site. It was quite frustrating.

It is not possible to completely protect us from this if I am right? But is there any way to at least reduce the redirects because some sites redirect us one after other site to show their same shitty ads.

Comment: I think Chrome 64 is going to block those by default: https://blog.chromium.org/2017/11/expanding-user-protections-on-web.html

Comment: Did you try adblocking? And if this does not help sites which employ such shady advertisements should be better avoided because you never know what shady tricks they come up with next to make money from their visitors. Remember that even if something seems to be free somebody has to pay for it at the end. And some try to make money the nice way and others the ugly way.

Comment: @ Steffen Ullrich I never tried a adblocker I will try that if it helps.And thanks for your advice.

Comment: For mobile, you may use Norootfirewall which is available on Google Play Market (I assume your phone OS is Android). By starting it, it creates a VPN tunnel, then redirects all traffic to that tunnel for filtering; if you start it and give no permission to your browser app, then for each request from the browser, it asks request (allow or deny). At first glance, it seems that you have much work to just browse but (in time) you can minimize malicious domains/IP addresses. Also, you can add predefined IP addresses and domains if you have a list of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the context, I understand you're referring to Chrome mobile.
This version doesn't allow addons, so you can't install any ad-blocker.

The first way to prevent (some) redirects is to browse in Desktop Mode. Many scripts will check if the browser is a mobile one before attempting a redirect.

The second is to block all URLs of malicious scripts from your router. This kinda works like an ad-blocker, but only works if you're connected to your own wifi network.

Finally, it looks like Google is trying to embed this type of security inside Chrome itself (see https://blog.chromium.org/2017/11/expanding-user-protections-on-web.html, thanks to Ajedi32 for the link).

Note: The malicious site knows your phone model because it's really easy to footprint a particular device from a web page (user agent, screen size, ...).
Those are all information your browser normally sends, and nothing to be worried about, unless for some reason you're also trying to stay anonymous.

Comment: Is the chrome and chromium is same? I am asking it because about some months ago, I unknowingly installed the chromium and because it usually comes as preloaded with some other software then i researched on internet that many sites was saying this was a chromium malware! Is it true? I am quite confused...

Comment: There are also firewalls available for Galaxy (and I assume other phones).  I've taken to blocking those but it's a big game of whack-a-mole.

Comment: Or install Firefox for Android, which supports the same extensions as the desktop version (like ublock Origin for adblocking).

Comment: @daya Chromium is the open source community version of Chrome. It is completely safe. The source code is 99.99% identical to Chrome, except it lacks certain proprietary codecs, trademarked material, and a type of tracking code. It is still an official Google product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firefox focus browser. This browser blocks annoying ads and malicious site redirections automatically.

Comment: This isn't a very good answer. It's also untrue, since there is no way to 100% prevent this without disabling redirects entirely (which would break much of the internet). Just because a browser tries to block ads and malicious sites does not mean it protects you from them.